# How to plot boxplots at once when your x variable has more than 10 values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the following code for plotting the variable TYPE (which has around 100 factors) vs the variable MEASURE. I don't mind having separate boxplots, but I will like to know if there is a way to plot or code all factors at once instead of one by one.

```
figa <- ggplot(dftest, aes(x = TYPE, y =  MEASURE))+
  geom_boxplot()
figa
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are plotting all the TYPE factors, and they are not readable.

I add `+coord_flip()` to boxplots to make the result more readable:

```
library(tidyverse)
g<-ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y =  Sepal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  coord_flip()
ggsave("test.png", g, height = 15 , width = 7) # tall 15x7 for example
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but they are still overlapping and not readable.

Comment: There are a few ways forward. Make the text smaller? Make the chart taller? see my edit